# jQuery animate width on button text change

Tags: jquery

If I have a button like this with default css, how can I make it so when you click the button, the text changes and it's width is animated to fit in the new text?

**HTML**

```
<button>Click Me</button>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).on("click", "button", function(){

    $(this).text("You have clicked me!", function(){
        $(this).animate({width:"auto"}, 1000);
    });

})
```

**jsFiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/HYZbA/41/

Comment: Isn't that what your example does?

Comment: What is your problem here?

Comment: @j08691 Wrong example, Updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot animate width/height to auto,

instead you give an invisible similar element width/height auto and saves their calculated value, then animate your own element with the calculated value.

Here is a [link](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/animate-heightwidth-to-auto/) that explain how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example that sort of works, you'll need to play with it a little
http://jsfiddle.net/HYZbA/47/

But as said by Tomzan, it isn't possible to animate width to auto, so that example uses the workaround.

I fix the width first, and then change the text and animate, this prevents the button doing auto width by itself.

```
$("button").bind("click", function(e){
$(this).css("width", $(this).width());
$(this).text("test test test test test test test");
$(this).animateAuto("width", 1000);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$("button").click(function () {
    var oldWidth = $(this).width();
    $(this).text("stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff");
    var newWidth = $(this).outerWidth();
    $(this).width(oldWidth);
    $("button").animate({
        width: newWidth + 'px'
    }, 1000);
})
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/HYZbA/49/)**

Comment: it is the same as my answer

Comment: Yes, you are right. outerWidth gives better result. Still, I would add function to reverse width to 'auto' value. Just in case different code on page is changing button label too.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
$("button").click(function(){
    var widthOld = $(this).width();
    $(this).text("You have clicked me!");
    var widthNew = $(this).width();
    $(this).animate({width: widthOld+'px'},0).animate({width:widthNew+"px"}, 1000,
       function() {$(this).css('width', 'auto');}
    ); 
});
```